# Paypal Adaptive Payment without Express Payment

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am trying to receive payment entirely on my website.

However, my biggest concern is that for tax reasons, I cannot receive that entire payment myself. In fact, what I will be doing is selling tours for other companies and I need my cut to come to my account and the balance to go to the tour company's account.

Can you help me with how I can do the entire transaction on my website (without being redirected to PayPal's account) and still disburse that amount automatically to the right accounts?

PS: I am familiar with Adaptive payments but it keeps requiring "Express Checkout" which requires you to be redirected to the PayPal site at some point, so that is not a good solution.